# Performance of different implementations of mapping two lists/arrays to a single list/array

Tags: f#

The following three implementations (`a`, `b`, `c`) give the same result

```
let l1 = [1..10]
let l2 = [11..20]

let avg1 = fun (x, y) -> (x+y)/2
let avg2 x y = (x+y)/2

let a = l1 |> List.zip l2 |> List.map avg1

let b = List.map2 avg2 l1 l2

let c = (l1, l2) ||> List.map2 avg2
```

I am trying to determine which implementation is the best in terms of speed.

Are the three implementations really identical?

Does the mapping actually produce a tuple of the elements of `l1` and `l2`, or is it the references to `l1` and `l2` that are being fed into the mapper?

Does the the result change if the `List` is changed to an `Array`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The calculations for `b` and `c` are exactly identical. From the F# source code:

```
let inline (||>) (x1,x2) f = f x1 x2
```

Inline functions are, as the name implies, inlined where called, transforming `c`'s expression to `b`'s expression before further compilation.

`a` is equivalent in terms of the result, but when used with "actual", larger data, I would expect it to be slower. I wouldn't expect the compiler to be smart enough to combine the zipping and the projection into one function, so there would be two iterations, probably allocating an entire intermediate list.

For just iterating over batches of data, arrays are usually faster than lists. But with arrays, you have to be more careful with whom to pass the data to, since they are mutable, unlike F# lists.

A rough performance estimate can be obtained from in F# interactive. With lists of `[1..1000000]` and `[1000001..2000000]` and `#time` enabled, the cost of `a` is shown as:

```
Real: 00:00:00.387, CPU: 00:00:00.436, GC gen0: 9, gen1: 4, gen2: 1
```

and `b` confirms a speed-up:

```
Real: 00:00:00.149, CPU: 00:00:00.140, GC gen0: 3, gen1: 2, gen2: 0
```

with `c` looking similar to `b` as expected. Note that this is not a very precise measurement, in subsequent runs I got about `0.080` seconds for `b` or `c`.

To put this it in perspective, `b` with arrays:

```
Real: 00:00:00.009, CPU: 00:00:00.015, GC gen0: 0, gen1: 0, gen2: 0
```

Due to the object overhead per item in lists, the array wins by a wide margin. So, this type of iterated throw-away buffer strongly prefers arrays for performance. Still, arrays need a large-object allocation, and eventually de-allocation, so in some situations, re-using existing arrays can bring another speed-up.

But using arrays, and mutating them especially, make the program less functional. Even in situations like this one, where arrays are a dozen times faster, This can be a high price to pay just to help the compiler optimize. *Always remember Knuth on premature optimization. Worry about these things in the rare cases where they matter more than brevity, legibility, robustness etc.*